# Unable to connect to denodo via jdbc driver to mavenized mule application

Tags: jdbc, mule, mulesoft, denodo

I’m trying to establish a connection with denodo using JDBC driver to mulesoft which is a maven based application.
Mule runtime: 3.8.6
Denodo version: Denodo 7.0 update-20181011
JDBC Jar used: denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-7.0-update-20181011.jar

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.denodo</groupId>
<artifactId>denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I’m using a generic database configuration to establish connection. I’m able to maven install the jar file and add maven dependency to pom file but when I try to lead driver classes available for denodo, I’m unable to find the right driver class. The classes I see are
com.denodo.util.security
com.denodo.util.logging

But I’m looking for this class. com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved with anypoint studio restart and reimport of jar file. For others who might stumble on this question I'm listing the steps I followed to connect denodo to mulesoft via JDBC driver.

1) Downloaded Jar file from denodo site. denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-7.0-update-20181011.jar
2) My mule project is mavenized, So, I had to install drivers using maven install command as follows. Install while you are on the project path on terminal. Make sure the path to denodo jar file is correct.
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Documents/denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-7.0-update-20181011.jar -DgroupId=com.denodo -DartifactId=denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver -Dversion=7.0 -Dpackaging=jar
3) Right-click on the project in any point studio and manually add maven dependency to the project. This should add denodo dependency to pom.xml. At this point, you should be able to see 'com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver listed under referenced libraries in the project.
4) Now, I chose to have a config file in global.xml. Add generic database configuration and fill in 'com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver' where driver class is required. 
5) DB URL should be in the format jdbc:vdb://denodo-host:port/database?user=test&password=test
6) with proper permissions to the server and right user name and password, you would be able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer really helped me. Here are the steps I took to connect to a Denodo 8.0 instance:

1. Download latest driver jar file ('denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20210209') from https://community.denodo.com/drivers/jdbc/34
   (the driver version and Denodo instance version need to match).
2. Add the Driver to your Mule Project.
   In your Mule flow, add a database operation (e.g. Select). Under Basic Settings, click to add a Connector configuration. From the Connection dropdown, choose 'Generic Connection'.
   In the General / Required Libraries section, choose Configure -> Use Local File. In the 'Choose local file' dialog, browse to your downloaded driver jar.

Add the Group Id, Artifact ID as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.denodo</groupId>
    <artifactId>denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20210209</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Configure connection properties

- url: jdbc:vdb://denodo-host:port/database (you can use `jdbc:denodo` with this driver version)
- driver: com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver

Troubleshooting:

- You should see the denodo dependency in pom.xml. You should also be able to see the jar file listed under 'Project Libraries' in the project.
- If you get SSL handshake errors, try adding `?ssl=true&sslTrustServerCertificate=true` to the url.